# Why are activities to do with a case hidden from contact records?

Tags: civicase

I have a case and it has some activities which are assigned to Betty. But when I visit Betty's contact record the activities are not listed there, neither is the case, in fact there seems to be absolutely no trace that this activity has been assigned to them.

The Activity tab for a contact record is useful for getting an overview of a contact's involvement with the organisation, so I don't understand why this would be missing?

Is this the designed behaviour, and if so, why?

(Civi 5.21 / Drupal 7)

Comment: Nb. I have made a pull request that would make showing/hiding activities a setting for CiviCase: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Demerit said it is intentionally not supported by CiviCRM to list Case activities under Activity tabs. We had to implement 2 lines of code via extension to have that available under Activity tab.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_config().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_config/
 */
function activitydashboard_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  CRM_Core_Component::getEnabledComponents();
  Civi::$statics['CRM_Core_Component']['info']['CiviCase']->info['showActivitiesInCore'] = 1;
}
```

If you implement above code than you may also need to apply fix from [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16353) which fixes an error in core.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Pradeep. Do you know WHY case activities were hidden? PS I've added a review to your PR.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it was intended. Let me see if I can find the original spec for more info.

UPDATE: Haven't found it yet but did find https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-3829 and also a reference that it is "in the spec" https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=6895.0.html

I know the reason is somewhere, but it has come up several times. Regardless of the original reason it seems to be one of the many things in Civi that 50% of people want it one way and 50% another.

I haven't tested this but I wonder what happens if you change `showActivitiesInCore` to `1` in CRM/Case/Info.php...

ANOTHER UPDATE: As I'm looking at the [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16360) I'm reminded that the CiviCase project at the time was also being used as a sandbox for this new thing called jQuery (the rest of civi used dojo), and so part of the reason besides business reasons might have been technical, as in "let's keep this separate so we can play with it without touching the rest of core". There's also some actions like "File on Case" that require some attention when the activity can live on both sides. I also remember at one time, but it seems fixed now, that there were multiple link formats to get to editing an activity, and if you used a non-case one the activity would get "downgraded" to a regular activity and get disconnected from the case.

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate that. I can't figure out a single reason this behaviour would be helpful!

Comment: I'm looking through the old wiki and jira but haven't found it yet. It had to do partly with segregation but there was more if I remember correctly.

Comment: wow you've been around CiviCRM for a while then?!

Comment: Wouldn't mind seeing that too. I'd assumed that, as the 'case' tab on the contact record shows all the cases and associated activities, it's likely down to permission levels for cases and the need to keep those separate from just the 'normal' activities.

Comment: Thanks for the update. "50% one way" - sounds like good case for it being a configurable setting to me!